# UITextField shouldChangeCharactersInRange

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7, uitextfield

I am implementing a textfield to input user passcode. I am trying to match the length of stored passcode with user entered passcode. When the length matches i try to validate passcode. If the passcode does not match or length gets greater than stored value then i try to clear the textfield (the `else-if`) but the last entered character still stays in text field.

Please propose what i am doing wrong or what is the proper way?

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
    {
            enteredPasscode = [enteredPasscode stringByAppendingString:string];
            if(enteredPasscode.length == [[self.passcodeFromDB stringValue] length])
            {
                [self performMatch:enteredPasscode];
            }
            else if(enteredPasscode.length > [[self.passcodeFromDB stringValue] length]){
                self.passcodeField.text = @"";
                textField.text = @"";
                enteredPasscode = @"";
            }
        return YES;
    }
```

Comment: return NO instead of YES

Comment: And use following:
    NSString *enteredPasscode = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to return NO; when you set everything to @"". I just checked and it works for me